# PHP Read file by file:// url

Tags: php, url, upload

I am trying to upload a few image files to my server using PHP, the URL that's sent to PHP is something like

> file:///Users/[user]/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0/Applications/[session
>   id]/Upload%20test.app/file.txt

I use this code to read the contents of the file:

```
$url = "someurl";

$file = fopen($url, "rb");

$filename = $id;

$newfile = fopen($filename, "wb");

echo "File path: ".$url."<br/>";
echo "File contents: <br/>";
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

But `file_get_contents();`returns nothing, any tips?

Comment: Using `fopen` and `file_get_contents` together is nonsense.

Comment: If the server is not the same physical machine as the uploading client, you cannot read a file on the client's machine from the server.

Comment: Why are you `fopen`ing two files if you are not reading from them?

Comment: Sorry, but I have zero experience with PHP so I just try the things I find on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not `read` this way, but you want to read data with in `local drive` you can write `full path` or `relative path` to get file contents,

#### demofile.txt

```
hello this is file first line.
this is another line.
```

#### index.php

```
<?php
    $url = "A:\wamp\www\demofile.txt";
    echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

#### Result

[image]